# Unexpected result bringing php array into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I've been searching around trying to find someone who has had this same problem, but no luck. That probably means I've boogered up like no one has boogered up before. Which wouldn't surprise me one bit.

At any rate, I'm trying to do something I thought would be pretty simple: get an array listing html files on the server through php, then display them in an iframe through an array javascript. The php code is as follows:

```
<?php
    $fileList = scandir('./slides');
    $jsFileList = json_encode($fileList);
?>
```

The javascript to create the array variable is this:

```
var jsFileList = '<?php echo $jsFileList;?>';
```

Now, when I first tried this, I didn't use json_encode, I just tried to receive the original $fileList array. That produced this array in JavaScript:

```
[0]: A
[1]: r
[2]: r
[3]: a
[4]: y
```

Then I thought, "Of course! It needs to be encoded as JSON data." But the current result is now:

```
[0]: [
[1]: "
[2]: .
[3]: "
[4]: ,
[5]: "
[6]: .
[7]: .
[8]: "
[9]: ,
[10]: "
[11]: s
[12]: l
[13]: i
[14]: d
[15]: e
[16]: 0
[17]: 2
[18]: .
[19]: h
[20]: t
[21]: m
[22]: l
[23]: "
[24]: ]
```

Why on earth is JavaScript creating an array out of all the characters instead of the three elements of the PHP array? I expected the JavaScript array to look like:

```
[0]: .
[1]: ..
[2]: slide02.html
```

Which is exactly what the PHP array looks like, but not the JavaScript array. FWIW, I also tried json_parse() in php, but that resulted in nothing showing up in JavaScript, and I tried declaring the JavaScript variable as an array first, but no change. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the JavaScript code you are using to take the Response and parse it into an array?

Comment: Don't forget to use JSON.parse(your_json_string) otherwise javascript will read it as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your code so it's clear what's escaped and what's not, like:

```
var jsFileList = <?php echo json_encode($fileList);?>;
```

Note no quotes here around the JSON value. It's already escaped.

You should always inspect the generated HTML source to make sure it looks valid.

Comment: Ok, like I figured, I'm a moron. Those single quotes shouldn't have been there. Took them out and it's working like it should. It's always the little things, isn't it? Thank-you so much for the help!